# How to fix blinking cursor that looks like a circle with diagonal line?

Tags: 22.04, cursor

I have an issue where my cursor looks like a circle with a diagonal line that keeps blinking, like this:[image]

This issue exists in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS when I updated to the `5.15.0-41-genric` kernel. Before that, I was using the `5.13.0-52-genric` kernel, and did not have this issue. It persisted when I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

It causes the system to automatically play a video if it is open anywhere and paused.

How can I fix this issue?

Also, the image is not my cursor it is some kind of error notification which comes when a key is pressed on the keyboard. In my case i think play/pause button is pressed internally(keyboard is absolutely fine).

Update : I tried all possible solutions i could get online which led to choosing an older version of linux kernel, so when i am using Ubuntu,Linux-`5.15.0-25-generic`. The issue seems to be resolved but the problem is every time i need to go into the boot menu and select this version from `Advance option for Ubuntu` tab, Is there anything I can do to make this one default?

Comment: I suggested an edit to your question to make it clearer, if I got something wrong please edit it to correct what I changed.

Comment: @Esther Thank you for suggesting the edits, I have posted for the first time so didn't had much clue about getting marked as duplicate and also I couldn't get that question while searching.